# how to map/rewrite multiple source and target URL from a file in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

### file ABC

```
sample/xyz/xyz/ should map to /abc/abc/
sample/foo/foo/ should map to /bar/bar/
```

### nginx.conf

```
include ABC

location sample/ {
   local url = ngx.var.uri #(uri = sample/xyz/xyz/)

   ######## Do something here so that variable url value is changed based on the value in File ABC########

   url = /abc/abc/ #(change URI after lookup from file ABC)
}
```

Comment: You can include a file in a `map` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

Comment: You're mixing in random snippets of Lua code in your `nginx` config; that doesn't work. The question also needs more information on what exactly you want to do; from what I understand you *might* be looking for the [`alias`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive? if not, [`rewrite`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) probably does what you want.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer added comment if that helps

Comment: It doesn't; you're still trying to write Lua code in an nginx config file, that just doesn't work like that.